# Searching Between dates in vb.net 2012

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Search_Record()
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty
        Try
            conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Data]"
            Dim d1, d2 As String
            d1 = Format(Me.dtpDOB1.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy")
            d2 = Format(Me.dtpDOB2.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy")
            Dim betchar As String = " where "
            Dim Orkey As String = " and"

            the date between d1 and d2 not working fine 

            If Not dtpDOB1.Text = " " Then
                If Not dtpDOB2.Text = " " Then
                    If Not d1 = "" Then sSQL = sSQL & betchar + " date = #" & d1 & "#"
                Else
                    If Not d1 = "" Then sSQL = sSQL & betchar + " date Between #" & d1 & "# AND #" & d2 & "#"
                End If
            End If

            cmd.CommandText = sSQL
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)
            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
            If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                MsgBox("No record found!")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ErrorToString)
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: See: [Writing Good Titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648) which was offered when you tried to post "Problem" in the title.  See also [Ask].  A little effort learning to format code would help too.  Then look into SQL Parameters and Data Types.

Comment: Are you using MS-Access as database?

Answer (score 0):

In every database system known the word DATE is regularly a reserved keyword. 
If you really want to use it (a very bad choice) then use square brackets around that word

```
 If Not d1 = "" Then sSQL = sSQL & betchar + " [date] ...
```

Said that I really suggest you to start using parameterized query to get better readability in your query and avoid any possibility of Sql Injection

```
Dim prm = new List(Of OleDbParameter)()
If Not dtpDOB1.Text = " " Then
    If Not dtpDOB2.Text = " " Then
        If Not d1 = "" Then 
            sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE [date] = ?"
            Dim p = new OleDbParameter()
            p.ParameterName = "d1"
            p.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
            p.Value = Me.dtpDOB1.Value
            prm.Add(p)
        End If
    Else
        If Not d1 = "" Then 
            sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE [date] >= ? AND [date] <= ?"
            Dim p = new OleDbParameter()
            p.ParameterName = "d1"
            p.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
            p.Value = Me.dtpDOB1.Value
            prm.Add(p)
            p = new OleDbParameter()
            p.ParameterName = "d2"
            p.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
            p.Value = Me.dtpDOB2.Value
            prm.Add(p)
       End If
    End If
End If

cmd.CommandText = sSQL
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(prm.ToArray())
da.SelectCommand = cmd
da.Fill(dt)
....
```

Comment: the problem not fix after use [date]  - if i change date to othername wil not work the problem in sql

Comment: What error did you get? Any error messages that could help to pinpoint the problem?

Comment: Change the catch to `MsgBox(ex.Message)` to see if there is an exception

Comment: Error 1 'OleDbParameter' is a type and cannot be used as an expression

Comment: Error 3 'p' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: it's vb project for my office